# What are the occupations of brothers of a king?

Tags: kshatriya, kings, governance

In general, the elder son of a king will become the next king, if eligible.

In which occupations the **brothers of the next king (elder brother) will settle**? Does it depends on individual or will there be any occupation for them?

Comment: they would still be Kastriyas and their duties would be same which are prescribed for Kastriyas...for example, they can join army/cabinet etc.. similarly how Arjuna, Bhima, Bharat, Laxmana joined when Yudhisthir or Rama became king...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What were the set of rights, permissions, duties or rules prescribed for Kshatriya caste?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/what-were-the-set-of-rights-permissions-duties-or-rules-prescribed-for-kshatri)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two verses showing about brother's activities.

> SB 9.11.25: Śukadeva Gosvāmī replied: After accepting the throne of
>   the government by the fervent request of His younger brother Bharata,
>   Lord Rāmacandra ordered His younger brothers to go out and conquer the
>   entire world, while He personally remained in the capital to give
>   audience to all the citizens and residents of the palace and supervise
>   the governmental affairs with His other assistants.
>
> SB 5.5.20: My dear boys, you are all born of My heart, which is the
>   seat of all spiritual qualities. Therefore you should not be like
>   materialistic and envious men. You should accept your eldest brother,
>   Bharata, who is exalted in devotional service. If you engage
>   yourselves in Bharata’s service, your service to him will include My
>   service, and you will rule the citizens automatically.

We may conclude that other brothers assist the elder brother's activities as the king.

Answer (score 3):

A brief  answer can be found in a book named [**"Studies in Hindu Law and Dharmaśāstra"**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=dziNBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA336&lpg=PA336&dq=occupations%20of%20kings%20brothers%20hinduism&source=bl&ots=Bow6XG2gYK&sig=BQkPqaf3UD4njdg0axt5wyRwlcM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz8car5brfAhVaWX0KHSFCAHkQ6AEwEXoECBAQAQ#v=onepage&q=occupations%20of%20kings%20brothers%20hinduism&f=false) written by Ludo Rocher . Page 337.

The author is quoting Shukra Niti Sara (शुक्रनिती सार) . And is clearly mentioning the occupations of brothers of a king.

> The text adds that younger brothers should rather be appointed
>   **governors of the provinces or superintendents of the royal stables , the treasury etc.** ( Shukra Niti Sara 1.346-48)

So it's clear that the kings brothers should be appointed on very high and respectable as well as very important positions as his aid.

Here is the screenshot of page no. 337
[image]

Comment: For some reason the exact page is not being shown in link . For time being i am just posting a screenshot of page no.337 , where the exact quote is present.